# Why does my update() method create a new instance?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, crud, enterprise, facade

I have a problem in the basic CRUD operations on a database in my J2EE Application.

Entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "shop_id")
```

Facade:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {

private Class<T> entityClass;

    public void edit(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Controller (I added S.out's to see what happens):

```
public String updateShop(Shop shop){
    System.out.println("Update ");
    System.out.println(this.shop.getName()+" - ID: "+ this.shop.getShopId());
    this.shop = shop;
    return "updateShop";
}

public String updateShop(){
    System.out.println("UpdateClick ");
    System.out.println(this.shop.getName()+" - ID: "+ this.shop.getShopId());
    this.shopfacade.edit(this.shop);
    return "shops";
}
```

And when I click on update, a new instance is created instead of modifying the one existing. This is the server's log output:

```
Info:   Update
Info:   Name - 41
Info:   UpdateClick
Info:   ChangedName - null
```

So the Id somehow disappears. This happens at the moment when I call updateShop(), because I display the ID on my JSF page and it works fine.

```
<h:outputText value="#{shopController.shop.shopId}" title="shopId" />
```

Any idea what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see the rest of your jsf to know what is binding to that shop

Comment: well, Common problem in Jsf, if you didnot bind Object properly. post the JSF code and Controller properly if you haven't Solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that [javax.persistence.EntityManager.merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-) returns an entity object - which your code is ignoring.

This returned entity may or may not be the same one that you pass in. Typically if the current persistence context already has a reference to the entity that you pass in then that will be the one that is returned.

Therefore, `updateShop()` should probably be something like:

```
public String updateShop(){
    System.out.println("UpdateClick ");
    System.out.println(this.shop.getName()+" - ID: "+ this.shop.getShopId());
    this.shop = this.shopfacade.edit(this.shop);
    return "shops";
}
```

Secondly, passing an entity bean without a primary key to `merge` is effectively the same as passing it to `persist`. Therefore if JSF has had to `new` it's own `Shop` object because you did not provide an existing one then you will get the duplicate effect that you're seeing.